# How to change attribute from a product?(SFCC)

Tags: javascript, product, commerce-cloud, attribute, b2c

I'm totally fresher on Salesforce B2c commerce and the instructor of the classes passed one task that i am struggling to solve.

Task:

- All the products sold by weight needed to change to unit.

For example:

- Apple 150g $2 => Apple 1 unit $2
- Apple 300g $4 => Apple 2 units $4

The costumer need to choose based upon the unit, not anymore in the weight.

On Business Manager I can change some products by Id of the product, but there are more than 100 products.

If someone could show me at least the path, i'll be greateful.

The website is almost the same used on storefront_base. Only the products are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, considering this is a task which is a part of a course you are taking, it may be worth reaching out to your instructor and asking them for a guideline. It is possible that your instructor may want you to do this once for a single product (not for the whole catalog), so that you can understand that changes you need to do in the Business Manager.

In any case, there are several ways to do this:

1. You could use batch processing from within the Business Manager https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/batch/b2c_batch_processing.html
2. You could use catalog export and import functionality, with a manual edit of the XML file between the export and import. You would need to have some understanding on the catalog.xsd XML schema and the different import modes. You may export a single product before and after editing it in Business Manager to see what the needed change is. https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/import_export/b2c_catalog_object_import_export.html https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/xsd/Schemas.html https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/import_export/b2c_import_modes.html
3. (Not applicable for your course situation, but important to know) In a real-life scenario this would be information that comes from a 3rd party PIM (Product Information Management) system. You would likely ask the engineering team that supports the PIM to make the change for you, so that you do not need to postprocess the catalog data provided by them. You can check some of the partner PIM providers on the Partner Marketplace https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_information_management https://www.salesforce.com/products/commerce-cloud/partner-marketplace/product-information-management/

Comment: Thanks but the instructor has informed that i needed to understand the work flow from Storefront: Starting from the view to the server side. He told me that i need to change the client side to change the attribute from the product(storefront/.../client/js/modules.js). In documentation i did not find many information about how client side works.

Comment: Are you sure you need to change attribute of a product and not of a product line item in the order? As products are readonly on the storefront.